# How to call controller method from async Task<IActionResult> method?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to call normal action method from my another method,but debugger does not go to that method.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    //Code Logic
    return RedirectToAction("SecondMethod");
}

public IActionResult SecondMethod()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: How exactly are those two methods related?

Comment: You don't invoke controller actions from other methods (or actions), its done by the routing middleware and your configured route

Comment: Question is currently unclear.

Comment: I have corrected the method name now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to redirect, this code will work.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    //Code Logic
    return RedirectToAction("SecondMethod","YourControllerName");
}

public IActionResult SecondMethod()
{
    return View();
}
```

Nothing special here, you just want to redirect to `SecondMethod` once the `UploadFile` is finished.

But you can't invoke it as a method since it uses `IActionResult` what `IActionResult` does is it defines a contract that represents the result of an action method.

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectToAction` results in a redirect being sent to the client's browser, which then has to request the URI being redirected to.

So calling `return RedirectToAction("SecondMethod");` will not invoke `SecondMethod` in and of itself, it depends on whether the client follows the redirect.

Comment: so what I should do to redirect?

Comment: but the redirect is not happening,means when i debug its not reaching second method code.

Comment: Is the call to `RedirectToAction` being executed?

Comment: yes but debugger did not reach second method,and on UI it shows "This page isn't working" HTTP Error 500 .